# Combinations of tower with different sized blocks

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have been given an optional task, and frankly speaking I have failed to solve it more times than I can count and that is driving me wild. I literally cannot focus on anything else, because my mind keeps trying to solve it.

The task focuses around building an imaginary tower of 2 x n blocks size, where n can be any value between 1 and 10^6. My job is to calculate all the combinations of such tower where I can use blocks of any size (meaning that I can use a block of 1 x 1, or a block of 8 x 2). We consider that tower as a 2D image so that mirrored and upside down towers are considered different, but a tower made out of 2 n x 1 blocks is considered as 1 combination, since mirroring it doesn't change it (if that makes sense). As an example if we want to build a tower of size n=2 we can do that in exactly 8 different ways

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOcUM.png)

my question is, how could I calculate those combinations?
I have tried a few different (but similar) approaches, and while they might be working for small towers, I can't even hope to calculate the combinations of 10^6 high tower withing this decade.

If you know of any article discussing that problem do please forward me to that and I will gladly learn from that.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).